# Error reported when trying to import prj for data points in New Brunswick Canada into QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, error

I have data points recorded with a Trimble GIS. The projection is [New Brunswick Sterographic Double Projection](http://www.snb.ca/e/6000/6904e.asp#6), which as near as I can find via a Google search is EPSG:2953. However, when I try to import the proj (see below) I get the error "not a valid or recognised data source". The same files import just fine into ARCMAP 10. How do I get these files to read correctly into QGIS 1.7.3 (Windows 7) or does this mean there is a bug in the projection data base of QGIS? I guess I could drop the projection and specify it in the program but I am concerned that the projection may be wrong if the files don't import correctly in the first place. Thanks

Alyre

Projection file:

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_CSRS_New_Brunswick_Stereographic",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983_CSRS",DATUM["D_North_American_1983_CSRS",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Double_Stereographic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",2500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",7500000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-66.5],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.999912],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",46.5],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Comment: What format is the data in? It doesn't sound like the projection is the issue, rather the data format itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the  ESRI wkt  or the ESRI .prj file at [EPSG:2953](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2953/) or fix the projection in QGIS after importing the file (without the prj file, if necessary)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

More Google searching came up with an answer. Unlike ARCMAP, you can't drag all the files, just the shape files.

Thanks for the leads and suggestions.

Alyre